# Cannot get css width working for MS outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I want text in a paragraph to be 100 px in width.

I try:

```
<p style="width:120px">This is some text in a paragraph. This is some text in a paragraph.
This is some text in a paragraph. This is some text in a paragraph.
This is some text in a paragraph. This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Outlook ignores the width.

Any idea how to get width working in outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to put the text in an table and set the width of the table.

Comment: Thanks! The best option is a mix between the two answers: <table width="600"><td>CONTENT</td></table>

Answer (score 6):

Try the old school version

```
<p width="120">
```

For email clients it's better to use all the deprecated attributes you won't normally look at. And even better - use tables.

Comment: As much as I hate what you're saying, I can't give a better answer than this.